# How to pass API image link to AsyncImage source

Tags: python, api, inheritance, kivy, parameter-passing

Part of main.py:

```
class search(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Builder.load_file('search.kv')
        super(search, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def searchNow(self):
        location = self.ids.location_search.text
        result = self.apiCall(location)
        tmpList = list()
        for entry in (result["data"]):
            tmpList.append(entry["result_object"]["location_string"])


        tmpList = list(dict.fromkeys(tmpList))
        count = len(tmpList)
        fill = 10 - count
        for i in range(fill):
            tmpList.append("")

        self.ids.sResult1.text = tmpList[0]
        self.ids.sResult2.text = tmpList[1]
        self.ids.sResult3.text = tmpList[2]
        self.ids.sResult4.text = tmpList[3]
        self.ids.sResult5.text = tmpList[4]
        self.ids.sResult6.text = tmpList[5]
        self.ids.sResult7.text = tmpList[6]
        self.ids.sResult8.text = tmpList[7]
        self.ids.sResult9.text = tmpList[8]
        self.ids.sResult10.text = tmpList[9]

        if (fill == 10):
            self.ids.sResult1.text = "No Search Results"

    def sR1(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult1.text)
    def sR2(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult2.text)
    def sR3(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult3.text)
    def sR4(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult4.text)
    def sR5(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult5.text)
    def sR6(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult6.text)
    def sR7(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult7.text)
    def sR8(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult8.text)
    def sR9(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult9.text)
    def sR10(self):
        if self.ids.sResult1.text == "":
             return
        self.dispSearchResult(self.ids.sResult10.text)

    def dispSearchResult(self, locString):
        result = self.apiCall(locString)
        SRname = (result["data"][0]["result_object"]["location_string"])
        SRimg = (result["data"][0]["result_object"]["photo"]["images"]["large"]["url"])
        SRdescription = (result["data"][0]["result_object"]["geo_description"])
        resultParams = list()
        resultParams[0] = SRname
        resultParams[1] = SRimg
        resultParams[2] = SRdescription
        SCREEN_MANAGER.current = 'sresult'




    def apiCall(self, location):
        url = "https://tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com/locations/search"

        querystring = {"query": location, "lang": "en_US", "units": "mi"}

        headers = {
            REDACTED
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        result = response.json()
        print (response.text)
        return result

class sresult(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Builder.load_file('sresult.kv')
        super(sresult, self).__init__(**kwargs)


Builder.load_file('main.kv')
SCREEN_MANAGER.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
SCREEN_MANAGER.add_widget(one(name='one'))
SCREEN_MANAGER.add_widget(why(name='why'))
SCREEN_MANAGER.add_widget(two(name='two'))
SCREEN_MANAGER.add_widget(search(name='search'))
SCREEN_MANAGER.add_widget(sresult(name='sresult'))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    TripMe().run()
```

sresult.kv:

```
<sresult>:
    name: 'sresult'
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        Image:
            source: "TRIPME.png"
            x: (root.width * .5)-100
            y: root.height * .8
            size_hint_x: 2
            allow_stretch: True

        AsyncImage:
            source: SRimg
```

I am having trouble passing the image link (along with the other variable `SRname` and `SRdescription`). I have tried doing `source: app.SRimg` and `source: Screen.SRimg`. I would like to avoid making global variables, but if you know how to make that work anything helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `id` to the `AsyncImage` in the `sresult.kv`:

```
<sresult>:
    name: 'sresult'
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        Image:
            source: "TRIPME.png"
            x: (root.width * .5)-100
            y: root.height * .8
            size_hint_x: 2
            allow_stretch: True

        AsyncImage:
            id: asyncimage
            source: SRimg
```

Then in your `dispSearchResult()` method, you can set the source using that `id` and the `SCREEN_MANAGER`:

```
def dispSearchResult(self, locString):
    result = self.apiCall(locString)
    SRname = (result["data"][0]["result_object"]["location_string"])
    SRimg = (result["data"][0]["result_object"]["photo"]["images"]["large"]["url"])
    SRdescription = (result["data"][0]["result_object"]["geo_description"])
    resultParams = list()
    resultParams[0] = SRname
    resultParams[1] = SRimg
    resultParams[2] = SRdescription

    # pass the URL of the image to the AsyncImage instance
    SCREEN_MANAGER.get_screen('sresult').ids.asynchimage.source = SRimg

    SCREEN_MANAGER.current = 'sresult'
```

I haven't tested this code, but I believe it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that and unfornuatley got an error:       12:        AsyncImage:
      13:            id: asyncimage
 >>   14:            source: SRimg
 ...
 NameError: name 'SRimg' is not defined

Comment: Just leave off the `source: SRimg` line from the 'sresult.kv'  file.

Comment: Ok I think there is progress, but I'm now getting this error:     File "C:/Users/Josh Benson/Documents/GitHub/tripMe/main.py", line 187, in dispSearchResult
     SCREEN_MANAGER.get_screen('sresult').ids.asynchimage.source = SRimg
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: That error suggests that the `ids` dictionary has not yet been built when that line is executed, Try swapping the two lines that reference `SCREEN_MANAGER` in `dispSearchResult()`.